# How do I prove\disprove the following logical statement?

Tags: logic

I saw this statement in one of my logic books and I was curious how to prove or disprove it?

> Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be sets of propositions. If $S_1$ is satisfied (all propositions in $S_1$ are true) and
>   $S_2$ is satisfied (all propositions in $S_2$) then $S_1 \cup S_2$ is satisfied (all propositions in $S_1 \cup S_2$ are true).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Satisfied by the same interpretation/valuation or *satisfiable* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\varphi$ be a sentence such that $\varphi$ and $\neg\varphi$ are both satisfiable. For example, let $G$ be the conjunction of the axioms for groups, let $A$ be a sentence saying that the group operation is commutative, and let $\varphi := G\land A$, so $M\models \varphi$ iff $M$ is an Abelian group, and $M\models $\neg\varphi$ iff $M$ is either not a group or is a non-Abelian group.

Let $S_1 = \{\varphi\}, S_2 = \{\neg\varphi\}$. Then both $S_1, S_2$ are satisfiable. But $S = S_1\cup S_2$ is not satisfiable: if $M\models S$, then $M\models \varphi$ and $M\models \neg\varphi$; but there is no such $M$.

Answer (score 0):

Take a statement $s\in S_1\cup S_2$. If $s\in S_1$ it is satisfied because all statements in $S_1$ are satisfied, and if $s\in S_2$ it is also satisfied because all statements in $S_2$ are satisfied. Since $s$ is arbitrary, we know that all statements in $S_1\cup S_2$ are satisfied, thus it is satisfied.